# Trim the unnecessary part of the noise effect

Tags: c++, direct2d

I'm drawing an image/rect ([Get current Direct2D render bitmap](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73064830/get-current-direct2d-render-bitmap/73089649#73089649)) with a blur effect and applying a noise effect.

[Blur 5f power and noise with 1f opacity](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pcMK1.png)
[Blur 10f power and noise with 1f opacity](https://i.stack.imgur.com/I8KJ9.png)

But I face the problem that when I start to draw the picture, the noise rect effect is slightly visible due to CLSID_D2D1Border, as I think.

[Blur 10f power and noise with 0.05f opacity 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Gzz2A.png)
[Blur 10f power and noise with 0.05f opacity 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YnYap.png)

My code

```
    var colorBrush = Brushes.CreateGetColorBrush(color);
    var bitmapNoise = LoadImage.LoadGetBitmapSource(@"C:\Users\me\Documents\DivineAloexGit\RenderAddition\TestImages\NoiseTest.png");
    var gaussBlureOffset = gaussBlurePower * 3.5f;

    ID2D1BitmapRenderTarget* bitmapTarget;
    RendererManager.DeviceContext->CreateCompatibleRenderTarget(&bitmapTarget);

    bitmapTarget->BeginDraw();
    var roundedRect = new RoundedRect()
    {
        rect = RectF.Create(gaussBlureOffset / 2, gaussBlureOffset / 2, rect.Width - gaussBlureOffset, rect.Height - gaussBlureOffset),
        radiusX = roundVector.X,
        radiusY = roundVector.Y,
    };
    bitmapTarget->FillRoundedRectangle(&roundedRect, colorBrush);
    bitmapTarget->EndDraw();

    ID2D1Bitmap* bitmap;
    bitmapTarget->GetBitmap(&bitmap);

    ID2D1Effect* noiseBitmapSourceEffect;
    RendererManager.DeviceContext->CreateEffect(D2D1Apis.CLSID_D2D1BitmapSource, &noiseBitmapSourceEffect);
    noiseBitmapSourceEffect->SetValue((uint)BitmapSourceProp.WicBitmapSource, PropertyType.Unknown, (byte*)&bitmapNoise, 8);

    ID2D1Effect* noiseBorderEffect;
    RendererManager.DeviceContext->CreateEffect(D2D1Apis.CLSID_D2D1Border, &noiseBorderEffect);
    var edgeX = BorderEdgeMode.Wrap;
    var edgeY = BorderEdgeMode.Wrap;
    noiseBorderEffect->SetValue((uint)BorderProp.EdgeModeX, PropertyType.Unknown, (byte*)&edgeX, sizeof(BorderEdgeMode));
    noiseBorderEffect->SetValue((uint)BorderProp.EdgeModeY, PropertyType.Unknown, (byte*)&edgeY, sizeof(BorderEdgeMode));
    noiseBorderEffect->SetInputEffect(0, noiseBitmapSourceEffect);

    ID2D1Effect* noiseOpacityEffect;
    RendererManager.DeviceContext->CreateEffect(D2D1Apis.CLSID_D2D1Opacity, &noiseOpacityEffect);
    noiseOpacityEffect->SetValue((uint)OpacityProp.Opacity, PropertyType.Unknown, (byte*)&noiseOpacity, sizeof(float));
    noiseOpacityEffect->SetInputEffect(0, noiseBorderEffect);

    //Console.WriteLine(rect.Width + "  " + (rect.Width + gaussBlureOffset));
    ID2D1Effect* gaussBlure;
    RendererManager.DeviceContext->CreateEffect(D2D1Apis.CLSID_D2D1GaussianBlur, &gaussBlure);
    gaussBlure->SetInput(0, (ID2D1Image*)bitmap);
    gaussBlure->SetValue((uint)GaussianBlurProp.StandardDeviation, PropertyType.Unknown, (byte*)&gaussBlurePower, sizeof(float));

    ID2D1Effect* compositeEffect;
    RendererManager.DeviceContext->CreateEffect(D2D1Apis.CLSID_D2D1Composite, &compositeEffect);
    var compositeSourceOver = CompositingMode.SourceOver;
    compositeEffect->SetValue((uint)CompositeProp.Mode, PropertyType.Unknown, (byte*)&compositeSourceOver, sizeof(CompositingMode));
    compositeEffect->SetInputEffect(0, noiseOpacityEffect);
    compositeEffect->SetInputEffect(1, gaussBlure);

    bitmapTarget->Release();
    bitmap->Release();
    noiseBitmapSourceEffect->Release();
    noiseBorderEffect->Release();
    noiseOpacityEffect->Release();
    gaussBlure->Release();
    //compositeEffect->Release();

    RoundedNoiseRectCache[effectKey] = (nint)compositeEffect;
    return compositeEffect;
```

I tried using CLSID_D2D12DAffineTransform, but it didn't work out. What ways could I solve the problem and save blur and blur border effect?

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer for myself in CompositeMode.SourceAtop. It turns out I used enum from system and because of this I didn't see most of the features